# Preventing textbox value from changing

Tags: c#, textbox

How do I prevent a textbox value from changing after a certain keypress? For example, I'm trying to prevent numbers from being input, if a number is input a message box is displayed however the number is still being printed. How can I get it so the number is not printed?

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '1')
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Only letters please");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, 
Ari

Comment: Here's what you're probably looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428205/validating-input-for-textbox-on-c-sharp-winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[0-9]"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Only letters please");
        textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "[0-9]", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: This brings the cursor to the start position if number is entered in between some text

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend really thinking through the decision to having the client doing a server request every time a key is pressed.
Or maybe this is client side validating? A Better option if you want to validate each letter.
If so... here is some scripts that can be used (not mine... just googled):
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/AllowingOnlyNumbersintoaTextBox.htm
http://justins-fat-tire.blogspot.com/2007/09/javascript-numeric-only-text-box.html

A good candidate solution may be that you validate this when submitting. Then you minimize amount of server requests.

/Cheers Magnus

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `KeyPress` event of the textbox and achieve only letters

```
void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     //allow backspace in case to remove some
     e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
}
```